# open source audio converter to mp3

Tags: php, open-source, mp3, media

I'm looking for an open source audio conversion library that can convert audio files of various types to MP3. The server I'm working with is a standard LAMP with PHP. Anyone aware of something that could be the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) can do this for you.  I might also recommend [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).  There is a [PHP extension for FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/), but I've found it is easiest to just execute it directly, as most ISPs won't install it for you.  Of course, this isn't an issue with your own servers.

Answer (score 4):

I found [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3583-PHP-Convert-MP3-and-WMA-to-audio-files-to-OGG-Vorbis.html)

However, I wouldn't rely on HTTP application processing of audio streams, since this is a computationally intensive process.

Anyway, converters such as *lame* can be invoked command-line and thus from PHP with `system()` call.

You can find the documentation of lame using `man lame` in Unix

Answer (score 2):

I usually use gstreamer for such purposes, since it will automatically detect most media formats and decode them for you:

`gst-launch filesrc location=input-file ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! lame bitrate=192 ! filesink location=output-file.mp3`

Of course you will have to invoke it from PHP as a separate process, but still.